# Were the Francevillian biota real?

Tags: evolution, fossil

The announced [discovery](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature09166) of macrofossils suggestive of large multicellular organisms 2.1 Ga ago is now over ten years old.

Is there by now a scientific consensus whether these constitute real fossils of an abortive early evolution of complex life, or real fossils ancestral to extant life, or simply pseudofossils just looking like complex life?

Comment: Interesting question, you might be better off posting it to the [Earth Science SE](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) site for this one. All the papers discussing these fossils were all from the same authors, so I can't say one-way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes they are real.

it is a a collection fossils that are different enough from modern forms it is difficult to say exactly what they are but they definitely exist. Occasionally someone proposes a specific individual fossil might be Pseudofossils but so far they have held up to a great deal of scrutiny. Some are too regular to even be disputed. much like the Ediacaran they are just forms very different from anything we are used too.

https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0099438

Comment: I'm also a believer in them, but I'm interested to find out on what basis you found that the scientific community put them under a lot of scrutiny? All I could find were papers published by the same group, admittedly largely in well respected journals, but nothing showing any form of debate - which may in itself be telling of acceptance.

Comment: don't expect to find a lot of authors of papers from different places for fossils. Funding, physical access, ad the lack of paleontologists  tend to mean only those very interested publish papers especially on invertebrates.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense, I had wondered if the situation were something like that - I don't imagine a whole bunch of people outside of geographically close countries get to Gabon in general.